# Multiple aggregations and Distinct Function in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I need to make some aggregations on streaming data from Kafka and output top 10 rows of result to console every M seconds.

```
    input_df = (
       spark
       .readStream
       .format("kafka")
       .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", brokers)
       .option("subscribe", "page_views")
       .load()
       .selectExpr('cast(value as string)')
    )

    ...
    ...

    # info has 2 cols: domain, uid  (info = transformation of input_df)
    # It's an example of what I want to do (like in simple pyspark)
    stat = (
        info
        .groupby('domain')
        .agg(
             F.count(F.col('UID')).alias('view'),
             F.countDistinct(F.col('UID')).alias('unique')
        )
        .sort(F.col("view").desc())
        .limit(10)
    )

    query = (
        stat
        .writeStream
        .outputMode("complete")
        .format("console")
        .option("truncate", "true")
        .start()
    )
```

This example without time trigger, but I can make it by myself. 
Because of it's not allowed to use countDistinct, I haven't ideas of making my exercise. 
I tried to make 2 dfs for each aggregation(df_1 = (domain, view), df_2 = (domain, unique)) and then join df_1 with df_2, but it's also not allowed to have several aggregations. So it's dead end for me. 
It will be cool to have decision for it.

Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 0):

You can make it by flatMapGroupWithState, which is arbitrary state function.Besides,it supports append mode and update mode.